# Not able to access class object in php file loaded via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am running into a little problem with the below, I am trying to learn for some future projects and need a hand.

Here is the setup:

1. I have a `user` class in php in a models directory.
2. I have a `home.php` file in my root directory.
3. I have included the model for the user class in the `home.php` file and am able to access it just fine.
4. I have a `profile.php` file that I would like to load via ajax onto the `home.php` file.
5. I am able to load the `profile.php` file just fine, however the problem is that the info on that page which is just being called via `<?php echo $user->first_name; ?>` is not being displayed when I load the page via ajax.  However if I load the page normally without ajax, it displays just fine.

What I have tried so far:

1. I have tried to include the user class in the profile page, however it is giving me an error that it is already included.
2. I would rather not place this into a session variable as I would like to be able to access the class from here.
3. I also need to be able to access the user class on other screens, that is why I have included it in the home.php file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am rather new to working with php and ajax.

Thanks

Here is some of the code that I am working with.

home.php

```
//Here we include are models that we need access to.
include 'apps/user/model/user.php';

$my_user = new User();
global $user;
$user    = $my_user->getUserById($_SESSION['loggedin_user_id']);
```

profile.php

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $user->username; ?>" class="input-xlarge">
```

javascript to load the form via ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'apps/user/view/profile.php',
    success: function(data){
             if(data != null) $("#content").html(data);
    }
});
```

I also get the following error when I view the console.

[01-Jun-2013 10:38:03] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: user in /Users/btackett1377/development/Test/Base/apps/user/view/profile.php on line 23

Comment: Post some code please. Where are you accessing this object?

Comment: Yes, do you haz the code?

Comment: The profile.php loads correctly, however the username is not displayed.  However, if I just call the form without using ajax, it will display the user name.

Comment: Where does the $user variable in profile.php comes from? It seems to me that your code should crash with an error like 'can't access property username of null'.

Comment: Thats what I am getting.  I have tried to include the user class on the profile.php form, however when it is loaded via ajax it gives me an error saying that it is already loaded.  So I was trying to set the $user variable as a global that I could access but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick either, unless I am just doing it wrong...which could easily be...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead of `include`? I would try requiring the user class in both the home and profile pages.

For your reference, PHP has four functions for including files:

- `include` - Blindly include the requested file with no regard for whether it's been included already. Warns you if the file is not found.
- `include_once` - Ensure that the file is only included once. Also warns you if the file is not found.
- `require` - Similar to `include`, but causes fatal error if the requested file could not be found.
- `require_once` - Similar to `include_once`, but causes fatal error if the file is not found.

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeet!!!  I tried using only the include before, I also needed to change the path to the file in my profile.php so that it was using the full file location path.  Thanks so much for the help as this has been a major pain in the neck, but I love learning new things!